# Unable to download Apple Developer keys after initial creation

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apple-developer

In my Apple developer account I have created a key for use with APNs across all my apps. On creation it allows me to download it once I have finished. After that the 'download' button is greyed-out and I can't download it again. Presumably this is by design.

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't allow a second download like you can for the certificates/profiles?

Comment: You can share original private key between different desktops if you want though.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't re-download the IOS Push Notification Auth key. Only public key is retained by Apple and a private key which you retain and protect.

See documentation section [*Provider-to-APNs Connection Trust*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1).

> Token-based provider connection trust: A provider using the
>   HTTP/2-based API can use JSON web tokens (JWT) to provide validation
>   credentials for connection with APNs. In this scheme, you provision a
>   public key to be retained by Apple, and a private key which you retain
>   and protect.

---

You can see warning too when you create an Auth Key.

> **Download and Back Up After downloading your key, it cannot be
>   re-downloaded as the server copy is removed**. If you are not prepared
>   to download your key at this time, click Done and download it at a
>   later time. Be sure to save a backup of your key in a secure place.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to revoke the key and generate new one? In my account it shows, it has exceeded the limits. I want to revoke it and generate a new one. Is this possible? Also will this affect existing apps?

Comment: @yaali Yes you can revoke and generate a new key. And Yes it will affect existing apps but only backend (NO APP CHANGE REQUIRED).  You must update keys in your backend (server) to keep receiving push notifications in your apps.

Comment: Currently we are using Microsoft Notification Hub to send the notifications to Apple devices. Now we are planing to migrate from Notification Hub to App Center. If we generate new authkey (which is required by App Center) from Apple Developer Portal will it affect the existing key which was automatically generated by Notification Hub in Azure.